# AWS CLI EMR get Master node Instance ID and tag it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I want to automate the running of a cluster and can use tags to get attributes of an EC2 instance like its instance-id.

The documentation on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html states that

> --tags (list)
>
> A list of tags to associate with a cluster, which apply to each Amazon
>   EC2 instance in the cluster. Tags are key-value pairs that consist of
>   a required key string with a maximum of 128 characters, and an
>   optional value string with a maximum of 256 characters.
>
> You can specify tags in key=value format or you can add a tag without
>   a value using only the key name, for example key . Use a space to
>   separate multiple tags.

So this applies tags to every EC2 instance including the master and slaves. How do I discern which instance is the master node?

**Additional Info:**
I am using the following command to get attributes from aws cli based on tags where you can replace the "Name" and "Prod" with your tags key-value pairs respectively.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances | select(.[].Tags[].Value | startswith("Prod") ) |   select(.[].Tags[].Key == "Name") |   {InstanceId: .[].InstanceId, PublicDnsName: .[].PublicDnsName, State: .[].State, LaunchTime: .[].LaunchTime, Tags: .[].Tags}   | [.]' | jq .[].InstanceId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted when you create an EMR cluster, the tags are the same for all nodes (Master, Slave, Task).

You will find that this process using the AWS CLI to be complicated. My recomendation is to review the examples below and then write a Python program to do this.

Process to add your own tags to the EC2 instances.

STEP 1: List your EMR Clusters:
`aws emr list-clusters`

This will output JSON:

```
{
    "Clusters": [
        {
            "Id": "j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM",
            "Name": "'MyCluster'",
            "Status": {
                "State": "WAITING",
                "StateChangeReason": {
                    "Message": "Cluster ready after last step completed."
                },
                "Timeline": {
                    "CreationDateTime": 1536626095.303,
                    "ReadyDateTime": 1536626568.482
                }
            },
            "NormalizedInstanceHours": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

STEP 2: Make a note of the Cluster ID from the JSON:

```
"Id": "j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM",
```

STEP 3: Describe your EMR Cluster:
`aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM`

This will output JSON (I have truncated this output to just the MASTER section):

```
{
    "Cluster": {
        "Id": "j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM",
        "Name": "'Test01'",
....
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "Id": "ig-2EHOYXFABCDEF",
                "Name": "Master Instance Group",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
                "InstanceGroupType": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
                "RequestedInstanceCount": 1,
                "RunningInstanceCount": 1,
                "Status": {
                    "State": "RUNNING",
                    "StateChangeReason": {
                        "Message": ""
                    },
                    "Timeline": {
                        "CreationDateTime": 1536626095.316,
                        "ReadyDateTime": 1536626533.886
                    }
                },
                "Configurations": [],
                "EbsBlockDevices": [],
                "ShrinkPolicy": {}
            },
....
        ]
    }
}
```

STEP 4: InstanceGroups is an array. Find the entry where `InstanceGroupType` is `MASTER`. Make note of the `Id`.

`"Id": "ig-2EHOYXFABCDEF",`

STEP 5: List your cluster instances:
`aws emr list-instances --cluster-id j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM`

This will output JSON (I have truncated the output):

```
{
    "Instances": [
....
        {
            "Id": "ci-31LGK4KIECHNY",
            "Ec2InstanceId": "i-0524ec45912345678",
            "PublicDnsName": "ec2-52-123-201-221.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
            "PublicIpAddress": "52.123.201.221",
            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-41-111.us-west-2.compute.internal",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.41.111",
            "Status": {
                "State": "RUNNING",
                "StateChangeReason": {},
                "Timeline": {
                    "CreationDateTime": 1536626164.073,
                    "ReadyDateTime": 1536626533.886
                }
            },
            "InstanceGroupId": "ig-2EHOYXFABCDEF",
            "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
            "InstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
            "EbsVolumes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

STEP 6: Find the matching `InstanceGroupId` `ig-2EHOYXFABCDEF`. This will give you the EC2 Instance ID for the MASTER: `"Ec2InstanceId": "i-0524ec45912345678"`

Step 7: Tag your EC2 instance:

`aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-0524ec45912345678 --tags Key=EMR,Value=MASTER`

The above steps might be simpler with `CLI Filters` and / or `jq`, but this should be enough information so that you know how to find and tag the EMR Master Instance.

Comment: Ah so I get the `Instance Group Id` from `aws emr describe-cluster` and use that to find `Instance ID` from `aws emr list-instances`. And I can find it without tags, and then apply tags for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below can be used to directly get instance Id

```
aws emr list-instances --cluster-id ${aws_emr_cluster.cluster.id} --instance- 
group-id ${aws_emr_cluster.cluster.master_instance_group.0.id}  --query 
'Instances[*].Ec2InstanceId' --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

In an enviroinment where you does not have the aws cli, you can `cat` the following file:

```sh
cat /mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json
```

An example of the content is the following one:

```
{
  "jobFlowId": "j-0000X0X0X00XX",
  "jobFlowCreationInstant": 1579512208006,
  "instanceCount": 2,
  "masterInstanceId": "i-00x0xx0000xxx0x00",
  "masterPrivateDnsName": "localhost",
  "masterInstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
  "slaveInstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
  "hadoopVersion": "2.8.5",
  "instanceGroups": [
    {
      "instanceGroupId": "ig-0XX00XX0X0XXX",
      "instanceGroupName": "Master - 1",
      "instanceRole": "Master",
      "marketType": "OnDemand",
      "instanceType": "m5.xlarge",
      "requestedInstanceCount": 1
    },
    {
      "instanceGroupId": "ig-000X0XXXXXXX",
      "instanceGroupName": "Core - 2",
      "instanceRole": "Core",
      "marketType": "OnDemand",
      "instanceType": "m5.xlarge",
      "requestedInstanceCount": 1
    }
  ]
```

NOTE: i've omitted the ID of the jobs using 0 where a number is expected and X where a ltter is expected.

Comment: Can you share a sample snippet of what the json looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically in 3 lines of code, without having to copy-paste any of the specific information:

```sh
# get cluster id
CLUSTER_ID=$(aws emr list-clusters --active --query "Clusters[0].Id" --output text)

# get instance id
INSTANCE_ID=$(aws emr list-instances --cluster-id $CLUSTER_ID --instance-group-types MASTER --query "Instances[0].Ec2InstanceId" --output text)

# tag
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $INSTANCE_ID --tags Key=EMR,Value=MASTER
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example is for *Instance Fleet*, it saves *Cluster ID*, *Instance Fleet ID* and *Master IP* as environment variables.

Replace cluster name "My-Cluster" to the actual cluster name.

```
export CLUSTER_ID=$(aws emr list-clusters --active --query 'Clusters[?Name==`My-Cluster`].Id' --output text)
export INSTANCE_FLEET=$(aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id $CLUSTER_ID | jq -r '.[].InstanceFleets | .[] | select(.InstanceFleetType=="MASTER") | .Id')
export PRIVATE_IP=aws emr list-instances --cluster-id $CLUSTER_ID --instance-fleet-id $INSTANCE_FLEET  --query 'Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

"Cleanest" way:

```
aws emr list-clusters --active
```

Search for Master cluster ID (j-xxxxxxxxxxx), then

```
aws emr list-instances --region {your_region} --instance-group-types MASTER --cluster-id j-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Immediately filters out the master instance(s) with it's information using **--instance-group-types MASTER** flag.

For tagging refers to the other answers with **aws {resource} create-tags** and --tag flag.