# JMESPath query for aws cli EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

How do I perform a "regex" type match on a start of a string in jmespath?

```
aws emr list-clusters --active --query 'Clusters[?Name==`My-Cluster`].Id' --output text
```

I was looking at the answers in [AWS CLI EMR get Master node Instance ID and tag it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256438/aws-cli-emr-get-master-node-instance-id-and-tag-it) and I can use most of the solution. However the my cluster name is variable (based on time it was built). So i need to edit the `Name=='My-Cluster'` to be able to search with a wild card at the end of the name. This way I can find My-Cluser-082022 then next month find MY-Cluster-092022 next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [`starts_with()`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with).

It would be something like:

```
Clusters[starts_with(Name, 'My-Cluster')].Id
```

Some good resources:

- [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [JMESPath Specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html)

Comment: That second link is great! I guess my internet searching was off because I kept coming back to the Tutorial page and I knew there had to be more.